# How to write If/else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
x = 1;    
if(x = 10) {x = 1;} 
else {x = x + 1;}
alert (x);
```

The result is always `1`, instead of `1,2,3...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace

```
if(x = 10) {x = 1;}
```

with

```
if(x == 10) {x = 1;}
```

Because `x=10` returns `10`, which in a test evaluates as true, and thus the code `{x = 1;}` is executed.

From [the MDN about if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) :

> Any value that is not undefined, null, 0, NaN, or the empty string
>   (""), and any object, including a Boolean object whose value is false,
>   evaluates to true when passed to a conditional statement

Answer (score 4):

```
x = 1;    
if(x
```

> ==

```
10) {x = 1;} 
    else {x = x + 1;}
    alert (x);
```

Answer (score 4):

if condition should be checked like below

```
x=1;
if(x == 10)
{x = 1;}
else
{x = x+ 1;}
 alert(x)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = 1;
x = (x == 10)? 1:x+=1;
alert(x);
```